# How to pass to tar.gz a file after rename using xargs?

Tags: command-line, find, tar, mv, xargs

I'm trying to rename log files and make tar them as 'tar.gz', I ended with below command but it doesn't get the renamed file name from STDIN (output of mv command) and it causes the `tar` command to create empty files,

```bsh
find -type f -name "logs*" -exec bash -c ' \
     mv "$0" "$0_$(date -r "$0" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")"| \
     xargs tar -czf "$0_$(date -r "$0" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")".tar.gz --null -T - 
' "{}" \;
```

How can I tar the renamed file with revised of above command or is there other ways (in bash shell)? thanks

Comment: Do you want a separate .tar.gz file for each input file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a separate `.tar.gz` file for each of the log files that find collects, you don't need to use `xargs`. You can save the dated appended name of each file to a variable (f in this case) and reuse the new name in the `tar` command. This will also leave your renamed files in place.

```bsh
find . -type f -iname "log*" -exec bash -c ' \
    f="${0}_$(date -r "$0" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")"; \
    mv "$0" "$f" && tar -czf "${f}.tar.gz" "$f" \
' "{}" \;
```